# Limit mouse movement to 2 montiors? (4 monitors all together)

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, cursor

I have 4 monitors, two of which are kiosks and are just playing looped powerpoints but the other two I need to have interactive. How can I limit my cursor movement to just monitors 1 an 2 an not allow any interaction with 3 and 4?

Comment: An ideal solution, I think, would have a hot key that allows access to 3 & 4 when you want it.

Comment: you could have no mouse and a touch screen for monitors 1 and 2. Monitors 3 and 4 are regular LCDs and therefore cannot be altered.

Comment: Unfortunately my situation involves the 4 (huge) monitors being mounted on a wall. It would be very awkward for the users to use a touch screen of this size and in this position. I have a wireless keyboard and mouse that they will be using.

Answer (score 4):

Ok Found a working version.

Please post back if it works on your 4 Monitor setup

Check out [Dual Monitor Software](http://www.murgee.com/MurGeeMon/)

UPDATE:

Found another application [Cursor lock](http://download.cnet.com/Cursor-Lock/3000-2072_4-10767852.html)

Comment: From what i gather from that webpage, Murgeemon allows you to "disable/enable" monitors. -But doing so simply turns the monitor off. I still want to be able to view them, I just dont want any acciental interaction with them.

Comment: According to the site "Lock Mouse is a feature of the MurGeeMon software utility that allows one to restrict the mouse cursor movements to a single monitor or restrict mouse on a monitor to prevent accidental straying of the mouse cursor to the other monitor. "

Comment: Thanks for your help David, I've now downloaded at tried both of these appications but they can only seem to restrict mouse movement to one monitor at a time. I need to restrict it so that its able to move across 2 of the 4 monitors.